# What is the Best E-commerce Paltform For B2B(open source)?

Tags: e-commerce, b2b

Is there any open source e-commerce platform for b2b, other than magento(B2B extension) which seem not avaliable now ?

Any Help appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is for questions about programming; shopping recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: Will you be selling products to businesses or services? E-commerce is not great for services unless it is a set price service you do, in which case a booking plugin on top of Magento seems to be a great solution.

Comment: I don't want shopping recommendations. I wanted to know the platforms that are available, so that I can start my R&D on b2b site creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [GoCart](http://gocartdv.com/). It is a very nice solution based on CodeIgniter Framework, light weight and easy to adapt.